# Will my headphone's microphone still work if I'm passing it through a USB-C to 3.5mm stereo cable?

Tags: ps4, audio-hardware

I have a pair of Bluedio t4s. If I buy a USB C to audio cable with 3 ring for headphones, will the headphones microphone work or will it do nothing to the Bluedio? I just bought them today for my PS4 with idea of using cord to talk to my friends and Bluetooth for music

[image: audio cable]

Comment: The plug you have in the photo does not transmit microphone data, it is a regular stereo cable.

Comment: That's why I asked if I were to buy one that did allow microphone if that would work with these headphones or if it's not compatible

Comment: It's a USB type c to 3.55 mm audio cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plug will does support a microphone. That plug has 3 rings, one for the right ear, left ear, and ground.

If that is the USB-C -> 3.5mm, you should get a new one that supports microphones as well. (I'm not sure if these exist, though they probably do)

If those are the headphones, they do not have a microphone on them.

Comment: Thanks it used the USB c port for charging and headphones like the iPhone but they gave me a cord that does not power the microphone I was just making sure if I bought a 6 $ cord that it would actually power the mic for these